# Got Canadian student visa without medical done!

Tags: canada, student-visa, medical

I got a Canadian student visa but no medical done yet. I got my passport with visa stamp. Is this okay? Am I going to have any problem later when I arrive in Canada?

I got my admission for Fall 2017 in a university in Toronto Mississauga. My visa process was done in Singapore and I applied from Bangladesh.

I'm going to be in Canada for 4 year undergrad course. The online application doesn't say anything about a medical exam. I got email confirmation of the approval of my visa and then got my passport with visa stamped. I was expecting a letter for medical test but didn't. So I am confused.

Comment: Residents of Singapore in the year before the application don't need a medical, but residents of Bangladesh do. What happened in Singapore? Also, does the online application status say anything about the medical exam?

Comment: Are you going to be in Canada for more than six months?

Comment: Yea it is 4 year undergrad course. Online application doesn't say anything about medical exam. I got email confirmation of approval of my visa and then got my passport with visa stamped. I was expecting a letter for medical test but didn't. So I am confused.

Comment: @DipenShah you can't. http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/medical/medexams-temp.asp is crystal clear in that: Wait for instructions once you have submitted your application or Get your exam before you submit your application. We still do not know whether the OP is in Singapore or Bangladesh. You need to talk to the CIC which of course is impossible from outside of Canada. I am completely stumped what to do. Call the embassy?

Comment: @chx, I got the same understanding... wait for the instruction from visa office then do medical. I was trying find phone number for embassy and what comes up in internet is phone number of  local VFS center. I called them and they are also confused.

Comment: Just wanted to know if you needed to do the medical afterwards?